# How else can we describe the volume of a lagrangian submanifold in a Kahler manifold?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Suppose $(V^{2g}, g, \omega, J)$ is an almost Kahler manifold. ie. $(V,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold with $\omega$-compatible almost complex structure $J$ ($J$ is a symplectomorphism) and such that $\omega(\cdot, J\cdot)$ coincides with a riemannian metric $g$ on $V$.

Suppose further that $L$ is a lagrangian submanifold of $V$. Then $L$ has a volume, as defined with respect to the riemannian metric $g$.

Nonetheless I want to believe that there still is an alternative expression of the metric quantity $vol(L,g)$ which exploits both the (almost) Kahler structure and the fact that the submanifold $L$ is lagrangian (ie. totally isotropic) and that we have a canonical decompostion $TM|L=TL \oplus T JL$, ie. the normal bundle of $L$ is precisely $JL$.

Can anybody testify or provide some evidence or enlightenment on this matter?

Alternatively, an even simpler question: if we suppose $V$ is closed, then can we give an expression to the volume of $V$ (wrt g) in terms of $vol(L,g)$ which depends essentially on the circumstances of $L$ being lagrangian and $g=\omega(\cdot, J\cdot)$?

Comment: Your definition of a Kahler manifold should also include the assumption that $J$ is integrable. What you defined is usually called an "almost Kahler" structure.

Comment: Also, $\omega^g$ is a $2g$-form so it cannot yield a volume form on any $g$-dimensional submanifold, Lagrangian or not.

Comment: sure, forgot to add integrable. And of course $\omega^g$ is not a volume form on any $g$-dimensional submanifold. I was hasty and should have given $g/2$ (when $g$ even) to emphasize just that $\omega$ vanishes on $L$, so it ''appears'' to give to no data on $J$. I'll correct this typos. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably closer in spirit to what you're looking for than what you've received in the comments. If $(V^{2m}, J, \omega, g)$ is Calabi-Yau (which for me means that $J$ is integrable, and the first Chern class $c_1(V) = 0$), then one can say much more. In this case there exists a holomorphic nowhere vanishing $(m,0)$ form $\Omega$, called the "holomorphic volume form." The form $\Omega$ is unique up to multiplication by a nowhere vanishing holomorphic function. We don't need to assume that $\Omega$ is parallel, but Yau's theorem does tell us (if $V$ is compact) that we can change the metric, keeping the Kaehler class $[\omega]$ unchanged, to make $\Omega$ parallel (and consequently also the new metric will be Ricci-flat.) But I have digressed.

In such a situation, if $L$ is Lagrangian, then it is well known that the restriction of $\Omega$ to $L$ is equal to $e^{i \theta} \mathrm{Vol_L}$, where $\mathrm{Vol}_L$ is the volume form of $L$ (with the induced metric) and $e^{i \theta}$ is the "phase" of the Lagrangian, where $\theta : L \to \mathbb R/ (2 \pi \mathbb Z)$ is a smooth, multivalued function on $L$. In addition, the mean curvature $H$ of $L$ in $V$ is given by $H = J \nabla \theta$. So the *minimal Lagrangian* submanifolds (vanishing mean curvature) correspond to those with *constant* phase function $\theta = \theta_0$. In this case, *if $L$ is compact*, then the volume of $L$ is given by

$\mathrm{Vol} (L) = \int_L \mathrm{Vol}_L = \int_L e^{-i \theta_0} \Omega = e^{- i \theta_0} [\Omega] \cdot [L],$

which is topological. (It looks complex, but it's actually real, because $[\Omega]$ is a class in $H^g(V, \mathbb C)$.) If you prefer, you can just replace $\Omega$ by $e^{- i \theta_0} \Omega$ to get rid of the phase factor.

Such "minimal Lagrangian" submanifolds, whose volume is purely topological, are also called *special Lagrangian* submanifolds, and are widely studied in calibrated geometry and differential geometric approaches to mirror symmetry. The best place to start looking is the text "[Riemannian Holonomy Groups and Calibrated Geometry](http://books.google.ca/books?id=3ciqJzDCq7EC&dq=inauthor:%22Dominic+D.+Joyce%22&source=bl&ots=dPtVp-uBKc&sig=hLiZFrkDLbEblYy2R_Qjq6FzPVc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G10uUNES4u_KAcCogdAL&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAw)" by Dominic Joyce and its multiple references.

I'm not sure how much of this will extend to the case of $J$ non-integrable and $c_1(V) \neq 0$. I'd have to think about it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer very much Spiro. This formula for the volume is impressive, although i do not really know what it means. In my own case, I am looking at the volumes of lagrangians which are rational inside a given symplectic lattice. More precisely, let's fix the standard Kahler structure $(\mathbb{R}^{2g}, \omega, J)$. We say $\Lambda$ is a \emph{symplectic lattice} if $\Lambda=A\mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ for $A \in Sp{2g}\mathbb{R}$. Notice that $\omega$ will be integral and unimodular on $\Lambda$. Let's say a lagrangian $\ell$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2g}$ is $\Lambda$-\emph{rational} if 








Comment: $\ell \cap \Lambda$ is a cocompact lattice in $\ell$. In this sense we have a volume $vol(\ell, \Lambda):=vol(\ell / \ell \cap \Lambda)$. Hence the volume of $\ell$ in $\Lambda$ is the volume of the compact embedded lagrangian $\ell / \ell \cap \Lambda$ in the torus $\mathbb{R}^{2g} / \Lambda$ equipped with its flat Kahler structure. Now we have a problem here, right? Since my assumptions are exactly that this torus is actually a principally polarized abelian variety. Now whatever...




Comment: that `means', it at least says that the first Chern class of the torus is nonzero (since $\omega$ is nontrivial on the torus). But we do have of course $c_1 \mathbb{R}^{2g}=0$, and i am computing volumes of lagrangian paralellipipeds. Now at this point i should like to know precisely `what' $\Omega$ is, what are the phases $\theta$ of these lagrangian parallelipipeds, and what is the computation that yields $[\Omega] \cdot [L]$? What confuses me is why the formula does not yield $Vol(L)=0$ for all lagrangian submanifolds in $\mathbb{R}^{2g}$? I'm admitting my own ignorance

Comment: because i truly do not understand why $[L] \neq 0$. ANyway, i need to think more on this. I'll look at your reference. Thank you again for your answer, it is tremendously motivating. 

Comment: I'll try to clear up some of your confusions, but I am also confused by some of your comments. First of all, $c_1$ of a torus is zero. (I'm talking about the first Chern class (with complex or real coefficients) of its tangent bundle. I don't know anything about principally polarized abelian varieties. You might be saying that $c_1$ has torsion? I am pretty sure that doesn't matter here. On $\mathbb R^{2g} \cong \mathbb C^g$, the form $\Omega$ is just $dz^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dz^g$. This descends to the quotient $\mathbb C^g / \Lambda$.

Comment: Also, the formula only applies to *minimal Lagrangian submanifolds*, since $H = J \nabla \theta$. Now there cannot exist a compact minimal submanifold in Euclidean space, and [I should have said this] the formula as stated can only make sense when your (minimal) Lagrangian submanifold is compact, since otherwise the integral may not exist. It can probably be made to work if you know that $L$ has nice asymptotic behaviour at infinity, but that probably involves more sophisticated "cohomology groups" so probably isn't strictly speaking topological.

Answer (score 1):

Take an open rectangle in $\mathbb R^2$ with side lengths $a$ and $b$. This is a Riemannian manifold, thus symplectic, and has an almost complex structure. The center line is a Lagrangian submanifold and has volume $a$.

Two versions of this whole ensemble are symplectomorphic if $a_1b_1=a_2b_2$. So the volume of the center line is not invariant under symplectomorphisms.

Comment: Ok, so what? This is no answer to my question. If we fix a Kahler structure on $(V,g)$, then every lagrangian submanifold has a well-defined volume (with respect to the Kahler structure). Your rectangle has varying Kahler structure, so of course lagrangians have different length. 

Comment: Rereading my question, I see that the point of your example is that one cannot expect volume to be a measure of only $\omega$, ie. at some point we have to refer to the metric $\omega(\cdot, J\cdot)$. 

Comment: Do you, after rereading, feel that there is a question still to be answered? (If it's the second question, then could you please clarify what you are looking for? You seem to request, if $vol(L,g)$ is not invariant under symplectomorphisms, an alternate measure which is not invariant under symplectomorphisms.)

Comment: I just want to know $vol(L,g)$ in another way. There may be possible another expression of $vol(L,g)$ which depends essentially on the circumstances of $L$ lagrangian, and $g=\omega(\cdot, J\cdot)$. OR does a Kahler structure on a symplectic manifold yield a different functional on lagrangians?

Comment: I should instead ask "does a Kahler structure SUGGEST its own functional on lagrangians?" ie. a riemannian metric yields many functionals over all submanifolds (ie. $g$ leads to Levi-Civita connections and curvature etc.). So what functionals (which are perhaps only meaningful on lagrangians) does an $\omega$-compatible almost-complex structure $J$ spawn?

Comment: I have no answer to these questions. My guess is that there is no interesting alternative formula for the volume that only works on Lagrangian submanifolds, since the formula for the volume is already so simple and direct, but I have no idea whether there are interesting entirely new functionals.

Comment: Formula for volume as simple and direct ?! i would hardly say so: any way you cut it, volume is a determinant, and determinants are hard to anticipate. For instance, if i give you two explicit matrices A, B which are nearly identical, there is no way you can tell me with any confidence which matrix has larger determinant (short of actually evaluating both determinants and comparing). My entire question is motivated by the complexity of volumes. I would like, in the decorated case of Kahler structure, for there to be a simpler mean.   

Comment: If you want to preserve both $J$ and $\omega$, it seems to me you might as well just talk about $g$.
But here's an idea for kicks: if you cut out a tubular neighborhood of the Lagrangian $L$, you can symplectically measure the volume of that neighborhood.  If you somehow could ensure that this neighborhood was isometric to $\epsilon T^*L$ instead of some other neighborhood of the 0-section of $T^*L$, or could otherwise ensure that the average fiber-direction volume is easy to calculate, you could get the volume of $L$ by dividing.  That's a big pair of "if"s though.

Comment: If I'm given, say, a region in $\mathbb R^n$ I want to compute the volume of, I can give you a Lagrangian submanfiold of $\mathbb R^{2n}$ with the same volume. So if you have some easy way to compute the volumes of Lagrangian submanifolds, then I have an easy way to compute the volume of everything else.

Comment: @will: we are looking for an alternative expression of volume---not an 'easier' expression. The question is about exploiting the hypotheses. For your example: say we have a compact region sitting in a standard lagrangian plane $L:y=o$. Then we can rotate $L$ via $e^{J\theta}L$ for $0\leq \theta <pi$. This gives a type of ''surface of revolution''. If we integrate this region against the riemannian volume element $vol_g$, then we're pretty close to having the volume of our original compact region, wouldn't you say?

Comment: i thought, since you said that your question was motivated by the complexity of volumes, you were interested in finding a simpler alternative. I argued that there is no simpler alternative. You can take the standard geometric formula for volume and apply whatever algebraic or analytic manipulations you like, but this will only make the formula more unwieldy. It's unclear why you want to do this. To compute volume, you clearly need to integrate something, which clearly needs to be the square root of a determinant. You know what it's the square root of the determinant of. What more do you want?

Comment: If I understand your "surface of revolution" construction, the volume has very little relationship tot the volume of the original object.If you apply it to a line segment in the plane, you get a semi-annulus.  One has area $(b-a)$, the other $\pi (b^2-a^2)/2$. How does that help?

Comment: Well, no that doesn't help so much. But it's also not so bad. For a given vector $v$, we get a semiannulus and can recover the length (ie. volume of the compact lagrangian $v$) via the coarea formula: area annulus/circumference of annulus gives us the arc length. So we DO get something reasonable. The vector as 'compact lagrangian' is really what i have in mind. Actually i'm interested in having $g$ linearly independant vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2g}$ spanning a lagrangian subspace and want an expression for the volume of their fundamental parallelipiped.  

Comment: Moreover I want to know something of which paths in $Sp(2g, \mathbb{R})$ will increase the volume of this parallelipiped. So an expression of the volume in terms of something else is desirable. 